# Present perfect or past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, past-perfect, perfect-aspect

> Since I have stopped working, I started to learn English at home.
>   Since I had stopped working,I started learning English at home.

Are both questions having the same meaning in this context?

Comment: I am going to repeat what several people suggested already: please have a look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please look at previous questions about the usage of present perfect vs. past perfect. This type of question has been asked numerous times.

Comment: Related: [Use of Past Simple vs Past perfect in sentences with since](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193602/use-of-past-simple-vs-past-perfect-in-sentences-with-since), and [When to use 'had been' + past participle of the verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95719/when-to-use-had-been-past-participle-of-the-verb)

Comment: and [Grammar: Had been + vb or has been + vb](Grammar: Had been + vb or has been + vb), and [“Didn't want to do X until Y happened” vs. “hadn't wanted to do X until Y happened”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167274/didnt-want-to-do-x-until-y-happened-vs-hadnt-wanted-to-do-x-until-y-happen/167279#167279), and [Present Perfect Vs Present Perfect Continuous and Simple Past/ Past Perfect Vs Past Perfect Continuous](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115419/present-perfect-vs-present-perfect-continuous-and-simple-past-past-perfect-vs-p/115483#115483);

Comment: and [Difference between “have had” and “having”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/208622/has-changed-since-march-1-vs-changed-on-march-1), and [I have been sick for the last week?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146449/i-have-been-sick-for-the-last-week); and [Correct tense for events which happend long time ago but still have direct connection with present time](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/81501/correct-tense-for-events-which-happend-long-time-ago-but-still-have-direct-conne). Many more others...